# Comparar uma subquery com outra subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas, tabela A e tabela B, cada uma com uma coluna chamada *texto*.
Ambas as tabelas possuem registros iguais até certo ponto, até o caractere '**=**'. O que quero fazer é um SELECT de todos os registros da tabela A em que os registros até o caractere '=' dela sejam iguais aos registros até o caractere '=' da tabela B. Tentei isto aqui, só que dá problema da subquery só poder retornar um valor.

```
SELECT texto FROM A
WHERE (SELECT LEFT(texto, POSITION("=" IN texto)) FROM A) = (SELECT LEFT(texto, POSITION("=" IN texto)) FROM B);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de fazer subquery, você pode fazer um `INNER JOIN` com `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT A.texto FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON
(LEFT(A.texto, POSITION("=" IN A.texto)) = LEFT(B.texto, POSITION("=" IN B.texto)))
GROUP BY A.texto
```

---

Para usar subquery, utilize `IN` desta forma:

```
SELECT texto FROM A
WHERE LEFT(texto, POSITION('=' IN texto))
IN
(SELECT LEFT(texto, POSITION('=' IN texto)) FROM B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ter esse resultado é necessário fazer um `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.`texto` FROM `A`
INNER JOIN `B` ON SUBSTR(A.`texto`, 1, POSITION("=" IN A.`texto`) - 1) = SUBSTR(B.`texto`, 1, POSITION("=" IN B.`texto`) - 1);
```